Convergence of $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum a\left(n\right)}{n\pi\left(n\right)}$ where $a(n)$ is OEIS sequence A046665.
Let $a\left(n\right)$ denote the difference between the largest and smallest prime factor of $n$ [A046665].
I was trying to find a good estimation for the sum of $a\left(n\right)$ and noticed that this was quite good for relatively small $n$:
$$\sum_{k\leq n}a\left(k\right)\sim\frac{n\pi\left(n\right)}{3}$$
where $\pi\left(n\right)$ is the prime counting function.
The question I'm trying to answer is whether or not the following limit should converge to some value $c$:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum a\left(n\right)}{n\pi\left(n\right)}=c$$
Looking at some computations we can see why I was getting a good estimation with $c=\frac{1}{3}$:



$n$
$\sum_{k\leq n}a\left(k\right)$
$c$




$10^1$
$4$
$0.1000000000$


$10^2$
$658$
$0.2632000000$


$10^3$
$56757$
$0.3378392857$


$10^4$
$4331829$
$0.3524677787$


$10^5$
$337813012$
$0.3521820392$


$10^6$
$27368918273$
$0.3486575234$


$10^7$
$2290651774547$
$0.3446771226$


$10^8$
$196782599523652$
$0.3415501805$



